# Inverse Document to Document (List) in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I am analyzing some text from the Microsoft Academic API and I am looking to consume the paper abstracts, but the abstract are given in inverse-document format i.e. {word : [Indices of occurrence of word in the document]}. I need to convert this to regular document. I have around 20,000 abstracts like this and I came up with an approach as follows, where result is the api output.

```
doc_length = result['entities'][0]['IA']['IndexLength'] #provided in the api output variable - result
output_list = [0] * doc_length
inv_doc = result['entities'][0]['IA']['InvertedIndex']
for key in inv_doc.keys():
    for index in inv_doc[key]:
        output_list[index] = key
```

The time complexity of the above approach is `O(N*M)` where N is the number of documents and M is the length of each document.

My question is can I do better in terms of time complexity?

Comment: To be clear: the above code only does a single document right?

Comment: When you're processing each document just once, how can you expect to do better than that?

Comment: We can process multiple documents together BTW. 
and yes this is for only one document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You cannot do better

At least as far as asymptotic complexity goes, your complexity is optimal. `O(NM)` is the size of the output. It is impossible to output something of size `O(NM)` any faster than `O(NM)` (unless the input is already part of the output, which is not the case here).

To see this, consider that the output takes up `O(NM)` memory. To get the output, if nothing else, you will have to access all of that memory. This in itself already takes `O(NM)` time.

Comment: so the lower bound is indeed O(NM)? Can we prove it somehow? Not asking for the proof just an intuitive direction beyond what you have written should suffic.

Comment: I would consider what I wrote a proof, as it's a very fundamental thing that writing `O(f(x))` things takes at least `O(f(x))` time. I've written a slightly more verbose explanation beneath it.